# How to display time on route as google maps

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkpolyline

[image]I have created route with multiple annotations.
I want to display text between annotations which exactly as attached screen shot.

Can any one help please?

Thanks

Comment: Attached image, i need to show time popover on MKPolyline which is same as attached image. Can you anyone have an idea Please?

Comment: have you tried just adding another annotation at a specific location?

Comment: @Wain thanks for the reply. Yes, i have tried by adding another annotation. but after doing this, viewForAnnotation is calling for both annotations(first set of annotations and midpoint annotation) and giving unexpected result.

Comment: Tell us about that attempt and the unexpected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried something which will show the distance between two annotation but not when you tap on the MKPolylineOverlay. One more important thing I am not maintaining any standards.

Here is my controller structure.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class RouteViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    //Rest of the code see below
}
```

First of all I'll add some annotation to map in the **viewDidLoad** delegate method as below.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.mapView.delegate = self

    let annotation1 = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation1.title = "Times Square"
    annotation1.coordinate =  CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.759011, longitude: -73.984472)

    let annotation2 = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation2.title = "Empire State Building"
    annotation2.coordinate =  CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.748441, longitude: -73.985564)

    let annotation3 = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation3.title = "Some Point"
    annotation3.coordinate =  CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.7484, longitude: -73.97)

    let arrayOfPoints = [ annotation1, annotation2, annotation3]
    self.mapView.addAnnotations(arrayOfPoints)
    self.mapView.centerCoordinate = annotation2.coordinate

    for (index, annotation) in arrayOfPoints.enumerate() {
        if index < (arrayOfPoints.count-1) {
            //I am taking the two consecutive annotation and performing the routing operation.
            self.directionHandlerMethod(annotation.coordinate, ePoint: arrayOfPoints[index+1].coordinate)
        }
    }
}
```

In the **directionHandlerMethod**, I am performing the actual request for direction as below,

```
func directionHandlerMethod(sPoint: CLLocationCoordinate2D, ePoint: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    let sourcePlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: sPoint, addressDictionary: nil)
    let destinationPlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: ePoint, addressDictionary: nil)
    let sourceMapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: sourcePlacemark)
    let destinationMapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: destinationPlacemark)

    let directionRequest = MKDirectionsRequest()
    directionRequest.source = sourceMapItem
    directionRequest.destination = destinationMapItem
    directionRequest.transportType = .Automobile
    let directions = MKDirections(request: directionRequest)
    directions.calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler {
        (response, error) -> Void in
        guard let response = response else {
            if let error = error {
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }
            return
        }
        //I am assuming that it will contain one and only one result so I am taking that one passing to addRoute method
        self.addRoute(response.routes[0])
    }
}
```

Next I am adding the polyline route on map in the **addRoute** method as below,

```
func addRoute(route: MKRoute) {
    let polyline = route.polyline

    //Here I am taking the centre point on the polyline and placing an annotation by giving the title as 'Route' and the distance in the subtitle
    let annoatation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annoatation.coordinate = MKCoordinateForMapPoint(polyline.points()[polyline.pointCount/2])
    annoatation.title = "Route"
    let timeInMinute = route.expectedTravelTime / 60
    let distanceString =  String.localizedStringWithFormat("%.2f %@", timeInMinute, timeInMinute>1 ? "minutes" : "minute")
    annoatation.subtitle = distanceString
    self.mapView.addAnnotation(annoatation)

    self.mapView.addOverlay(polyline)
}
```

Next I am implementing the **rendererForOverlay** delegate method as below,

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
    renderer.strokeColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    renderer.lineWidth = 2
    renderer.lineCap = .Butt
    renderer.lineJoin = .Round
    return renderer
}
```

Next one is the important one delegate method which is **viewForAnnotation**. Here I am doing some things like placing the label instead of the annotation as below,

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if annotation.title != nil && annotation.title!! == "Route" {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
        label.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 30)
        label.text = annotation.subtitle ?? ""
        let view = MKAnnotationView()
        view.addSubview(label)
        return view
    }
    return nil
}
```